# Javascript callback inside promise

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I have a problem exporting data from mongoDB to javascript. So, I am using promises with mongoDB, and also I use .toArray() method, to retrieve data.
What I am trying to pass data to next .then() inside callback.

Here is my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/website';

MongoClient.connect(url)
.then((db, err) => { assert.equal(null, err); return [db, err] })
.then(([db, err]) => {
    return [db.collection('goodsList'), db];
})
.then(([collection, db]) => {
    function toArr(collection) {
        var documents = collection.find({}).toArray( function(err, docs) {
            return docs;
        })
    }
    return [toArr(collection), db]
})
.then(([docs, db]) => {
    console.log(docs)
    console.log(db)
    db.close()
})
.catch ((err) => {throw err})
```

It returns undefined and 'Db' object. i know the code is broken, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `function toArr(collection) {` doesn't return anything - that's where `undefined` is coming from - replace `var documents = ` with `return`

Comment: It doesn't throw any error.

Comment: İ think the problem might the timing between return and  toArr function, can you check/debug that if toArr function is comsuming some time but return does not wait for it? If that is the case then put that return combined inside the toArr function.

Comment: `It doesn't throw any error` so? it's perfectly OK to not return from a function, that's where `undefined` is coming from!!

Comment: function toArr(collection) {
  return collection.find({}).toArray( function(err, docs) {
   return docs;
  })
 } still returns undefined

Comment: is `collection.find({})` asyncrhonous by chance? If so, the solution is a little (not a lot) more complex

Comment: Actually, I don't know. I think it's because asynchronous callback.

Comment: so, `.toArray` is asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, i think so. But it's all code I have

Comment: Isn't it asyncronous? I think it is the trouble. Maybe there is other way to reach .toArray() results?

Comment: I can't follow mongodb documentation - it's pathetic ... some other docs suggest you can use either a callback or, with no callback `toArray` returns a promise - if this is the case, you can do `.then(([collection, db]) => collection.find({}).toArray().then(docs => [docs, db]))`

Comment: `.catch ((err) => {throw err})` is redundant - don't do that

Comment: Okay, what is alternative to this `.catch` code?

Comment: Okay, let me try this one

Comment: if you `throw` in `.catch` like that, it's just the same as not having the .catch at all

Comment: Yay, it works! Thank you a lot! Are you going to write an answer?

Comment: I will now that I know the I finally found documentation that made sense :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `.toArray` returns a promise, you need to rewrite your code to wait for that promise - no need for that function inside the .then either, as you can see in the code below

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/website';

MongoClient.connect(url)
.then((db, err) => { 
    assert.equal(null, err); 
    return [db, err];
})
.then(([db, err]) => {
    return [db.collection('goodsList'), db];
})
.then(([collection, db]) => 
    // wait for .toArray to resolve then return [docs, db]
    collection.find({}).toArray()
    .then(docs => [docs, db])
)
.then(([docs, db]) => {
    console.log(docs)
    console.log(db)
    db.close()
});
```

the last line in your code

```
.catch ((err) => {throw err}) // no need for this
```

is redundant, it's virtually identical to not having that code at all!